# what happens when an object derives from MarshalByRefObject and is also marked [Serializable]?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, .net-remoting

I'm working on my first project that uses AppDomains and I'm wondering what happens when an object derives from MarshalByRefObject and is also marked [Serializable]?

for example:

```
[Serializable]
public class DummyClass: MarshalByRefObject
{

}
```

Comment: It becomes serializable? What do you mean "what happens"? Did you read the documentation for those two items?

Comment: @CodyGray: If you have ask about 'what happens?' then you are not intimately familiar with .NET remoting.

Comment: @Ravi: I think best is to set up a small server scenario and test it :)  Perhaps being derived from `MarshalByRefObject` will 'veto' serializable.

Comment: @leppie It does indeed, though not by vetoing the serialisation, but by changing it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It gets marshalled by reference, but can still be serialised for other use-cases for serialisation. There's an implementation detail to this that is interesting enough to be worth noting: The formatter that is serialising for remoting uses a `SurrogateSelector` that will produce a proxy for any `MarshalByRefObject` it serialises, hence serialising will still result in marshalling by reference. Other serialisation uses won't have that `SurrogateSelector` and so won't have that effect.

Comment: what is the meaning of marshalled here, can you elaborate please?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad that's more a separate question than a comment on this question and answer. One that is perhaps duplicated at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600761/what-is-marshalling-what-is-happening-when-something-is-marshalled and certainly should be answerable by googling.

Comment: i asked few seconds ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295644/what-does-actually-marshalbyref-means