# how to use c++ libraries(.lib) in c# WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-c++, .lib

I have a library(.lib) which as been implemented in VC++. I want to include or use this library in c# wpf project how can i achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [marshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240804/marshalling-what-is-it-and-why-do-we-need-it) to access C++ code in your C# code.

Have a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=vs.110).aspx), too.

An example

```
[DllImport("example.dll")]
static public extern void DoSomething(int value);
```

and you can use your method in your C# code like usual

```
DoSomething(42);
```

Can be a bit confusing because you have to "map" the C++ types to C# and reverse.