# C++/CLI project, wraper for C++ shared library, get error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++-cli, open3d

I am trying to use [Open3d](https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D) as C++ in managed code C#.

I managed to make a dynamic shared library of open3d as runtime library MD(Multi-threaded DLL). And then add Open3D.lib to the C++/CLI project, but when I compile it I got an LNK2005 error like below:

```
Error   LNK2005 "public: virtual char const * __cdecl std::exception::what(void)const " 
(?what@exception@std@@UEBAPEBDXZ) already defined in Open3D.lib(Open3D.dll) 
Open3D wrapper test C:\Users\tpgns\source\repos\Open3dWrapperDll\Open3D wrapper test\MSVCRT.lib(throw_bad_alloc.obj)
```

As searching through StackOverflow, found a [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287888/linking-error-while-in-c-cli-project-while-wrapping-c-shared-library/53424589#53424589) which seems the exact solution for my problem, but I can't understand the solution.

> 1. Turn off CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS.
> 2. Export/import explicitly the desired symbols from the DLL (using __declspec(export|import).

When I turn off CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS in CMakeLists.txt for building Open3D, I can't build the Open3d library. And It seems impossible to add `__declspec(export)` for every variable inside the Open3d library.

Is there any other solution for my problem? Or is there missing parts in my method to follow the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287888/linking-error-while-in-c-cli-project-while-wrapping-c-shared-library/53424589#53424589) solution?

Comment: You're probably using a mix of runtime libraries, all code in a dll needs to use the same runtime setting

Comment: @AlanBirtles As I know I set all runtime libraries as x64 /MD, release.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to use Open3d Library in C++/CLI by build open3d as **not** use static windows runtime library and **not** build a shared library.

It works fine when I change CMakeList options as

```
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS    "Build shared libraries"    OFF)
option (STATIC_WINDOWS_RUNTIME     "Use static (MT/MTd) Windows runtime"      OFF)
```

I think It is almost impossible to use the Open3D shared library in C++/CLI.